# Google places review, arraylist in jsonparser

Tags: java, android, python, xml, json

I got a problem so I'm using the **google places api**.

I will not write the whole code here because it's too big. But this is what I get for resuls whenever I call the google api:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "NSW",
            "short_name" : "NSW",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "AU",
            "short_name" : "AU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "2009",
            "short_name" : "2009",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "events" : [
        {
          "event_id" : "9lJ_jK1GfhX",
          "start_time" : 1293865200,
          "summary" : "<p>A visit from author John Doe, who will read from his latest book.</p>
                       <p>A limited number of signed copies will be available.</p>",
          "url" : "http://www.example.com/john_doe_visit.html"
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8669710,
           "lng" : 151.1958750
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
      "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
      "name" : "Google Sydney",
      "rating" : 4.70,
      "reference" : "CnRsAAAA98C4wD-VFvzGq-KHVEFhlHuy1TD1W6UYZw7KjuvfVsKMRZkbCVBVDxXFOOCM108n9PuJMJxeAxix3WB6B16c1p2bY1ZQyOrcu1d9247xQhUmPgYjN37JMo5QBsWipTsnoIZA9yAzA-0pnxFM6yAcDhIQbU0z05f3xD3m9NQnhEDjvBoUw-BdcocVpXzKFcnMXUpf-nkyF1w",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "quality"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Simon Bengtsson",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/104675092887960962573",
            "text" : "Just went inside to have a look at Google. Amazing.",
            "time" : 1338440552869
         },
         {
           "aspects" : [
              {
                 "rating" : 3,
                 "type" : "quality"
              }
             ],
            "author_name" : "Felix Rauch Valenti",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/103291556674373289857",
            "text" : "Best place to work :-)",
            "time" : 1338411244325
         },
         {
           "aspects" : [
              {
                 "rating" : 3,
                 "type" : "quality"
              }
             ],
            "author_name" : "Chris",
            "text" : "Great place to work, always lots of free food!",
            "time" : 1330467089039
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "establishment" ],
      "url" : "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website" : "http://www.google.com.au/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now I all save that here:

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

/** Implement this class from "Serializable"
* So that you can pass this class Object to another using Intents
* Otherwise you can't pass to another actitivy
* */
public class Place implements Serializable {

    @Key
    public String id;

    @Key
    public String name;

    @Key
    public String reference;

    @Key
    public String icon;

    @Key
    public String vicinity;

    @Key
    public Geometry geometry;

    @Key
    public String formatted_address;

    @Key
    public String formatted_phone_number;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " - " + id + " - " + reference;
    }

    public static class Geometry implements Serializable
    {
        @Key
        public Location location;
    }

    public static class Location implements Serializable
    {
        @Key
        public double lat;

        @Key
        public double lng;
    }

}
```

Here is how I get the results:

```
public class PlacesList implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Key
    public String status;

    @Key
    public List<Place> results;



}
```

Now my question is:

**In the result i get from google you can see the photo_reference. But it's an array and I just need to have the first photo_reference. How can I get that in my code?**

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the json in general? Clarify a little more please?

Comment: I need the photo_reference. So what I wanted to do is put @Key
        public String photo_reference; in the class PLACE. But that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject res = // your google api results
JSONArray photos = res.getJSONArray("photo_reference"); // Extract the JSONArray

// Get the item at index 0, which should be a reference to the first image
String photo = photos.getString(0);
```

This will get you the reference to the photo, then it looks like you have to make another request to the Photo API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters
```

For more information on how to use the Photo API, look at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos

Comment: But I got the results in another class please look at the question again I edited it.

Comment: I need the photo_reference. So what I wanted to do is put @Key public String photo_reference; in the class PLACE. But that doesn't work